# How can I use Pipe symbol "|" from Java to Batch file?

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, cmd, runtime

I'm using java in eclipse to call a .bat file using Runtime method.
I have two options, send a variable or multiple variables. My unique option is to separate it with pipe "|".

when I send a unique variable it assumes correct and run the .bat file, but when I add the symbol "|" to the string it doesn't open the .bat file, even when I only show what I send. (the problem actually I think, somehow the pipe cut the runtime process).

The problem is that I need to send something like:
1st example .- a (Just a character it works fine.)
2nd example .- a|b|c|d|e (more than 1 variable separated by pipe, the .bat never opens)

Comment: Can you show how you call the .bat file?

Answer (score 1):

Pipe is a reserved character. You can escape it by replacing it with `^|`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. ;)